# NSFileManager 'copyItemAtPath:' creates quarantined file copies

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsfilemanager

I have a sandboxed OS X app where I copy a file from the app's `/Contents/Resources/` folder to `NSHomeDirectory()`. All works well except that the copied file is marked as quarantined. Running `xattr -l` in terminal gives the following output:

```
$ xattr -l myfile
com.apple.quarantine: 0006;00000000;
```

How can I copy the file without having it being marked as quarantied, or worst case, how can I remove this attribute programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OS X` automatically quarantines certain files (executable, shell scripts, web archives, etc.) for `sandboxed apps`. There's an `entitlement` that you can manually include to prevent this:

```
com.apple.security.files.user-selected.executable
```

> NOTE: This entitlement does not have an Xcode checkbox, and thus must
>   be added to your app’s entitlement property list manually

↳ [App Sandbox Entitlement Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW5)

Comment: So the very first file copy I tested after adding the entitlement did not get quarantined, but now all subsequent file copies are being quarantined again! Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: @Tarek, What type of file(s) are you are copying, etc? It might just be a matter of changing the entitlements to match the files. Also which gatekeeper setting is selected in system preferences > security & privacy.

Comment: I am copying application (.app) files. Gatekeeper setting is "Mac App Store and identified developers".

Comment: Hmmm... so you are essentially copying another application bundle (.app) out of the sandbox into the users home directory? I'm not sure that's going to work with the standard entitlements. It might be possible to put it into an archive then copy and extract it, although you might run into the same issue once unarchived. If the .app has the same code signing signature as the application that copies it I'm not sure if it still gets a quarantine flag associated with it.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try the archiving option. Is there any unarchiving API available? (searched but couldn't find any)